Do I need to dry sealed TPU?
Bambu Lab recommends drying TPU 95A HF before use, in contrast to the more beginner friendly PLA.
Does this rule also apply if I am still using factory-sealed filament? Can I rely on the filament being ready to use out of the box, or should I dry it to be on the safe side?

You can almost be assured that a factory sealed package of TPU has excess moisture. If you want to run a test part before you dry it, you will be able to see the difference in the quality of the print both before and after the drying.
I'd suggest that you make no effort to tune the printer to the filament (temperature tower, etc.) until you've dried it, as there will be substantial quality improvement once it is dried.
You can also consider to use your preferred search engine for "TPU filament before and after drying" to see what others have posted. Expect a smoother surface and far less stringing (not zero) after the TPU is dried.

The image above is a result of a search as noted, although the source indicates it was unbagged filament. The other images I've found in my "travels" have included fresh-from-the-box before-and-after shots.
